# Pass params to function when using on() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A senior of mine advise me to always write using snytax 2, but I have some issue with passing parameters. If my function coloring has 2 params, how I pass them in?

```
//snytax 1
$("body").on("li","click",function(){
    $(this).css({'color:red'});
});

//snytax 2
$("body").on("li","click", coloring);

function coloring(param1,param2){
//what to do here?
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to pass into the function?

Comment: @cyberbit for example `$(this)`

Comment: `$(this)` would work as expected. `this` is overridden by `.on()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `event.data` like below:

Sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").on("click", {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  }, callme);

});

function callme(event) {
  var data = event.data;
  alert(data.a)
  alert(data.b)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click me!</button>
```

In case you were wondering if you can directly do this:

```
 $(".btn").on("click", callme(a,b)); // This would call the function when the event is bound. So, even without the click the function is invoked.
```

Comment: if I do `$(".btn").on("click", callme(a,b));` I still need to call `event.a` to get `a`'s value?

Comment: @HarisZ: No you need not. You can refer directly. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/qaLb0myt/